# Single SQL query to check if either table contains a row with column=x

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 unrelated tables A and B which both have foreign key constraints on C.  I need to run an sql query that determines if either A or B contain a given id of C.  My first approach was to use the union all but A and B are not related thus it will not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "determins if either A or B contain"? What output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to return 1 if either A.someFK or B.someFK = provided value.  I could run two queries via jdbc and do the logic in Java but if I can have just one JDBC query that would make it much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're asking but if you mean to return the elements of A and B that match the id in C then this will do it.

```
Select c.*, a.*, b.*
From c.id
    Left Outer Join a On a.id  = c.id
    Left Outer Join b On b.id = c.id
Where c.id = @somevalue and (a.id Is Not Null or b.id Is Not Null)
```

Where @somevalue is the value you're looking for.

Comment: Performance wise, this is probably not the best solution as it will always result int table 'a','b' and 'c' being accessed. You shouldn't need to access 'c' at all, and may benefit from accessing 'a' and only accessing 'b' if 'a' doesn't match (or vice versa).

Answer (score 5):

```
Select 1 
From   DUAL
Where Exists ( Select null From Table_A Where a.fk = :id ) OR 
      Exists ( Select null From Table_B Where b.fk = :id );
```

Comment: "from dual" would be better than "from table_c", otherwise you'll get one result row for each row in table_c, since you didn't specify a criteria on it.

Answer (score 3):

You could indeed use union, why not? But why use UNION ALL, and not just UNION? Just pick the one common column:

```
SELECT 1 
FROM 
       (select A.fk from A inner join C on A.FK = C.pk 
        UNION 
        select B.fk from B inner join C on B.FK = C.pk) AS bothTables 
WHERE fk = 'desiredValue';
```

This would work just nicely.

Tested it on the following tables in MySQL, with myValue = 1, just to verify.

```
mysql> select * from A;
+------+--------+------+
| pk   | value  | fk   |
+------+--------+------+
|    1 | ape    |    2 | 
|    2 | fjfjfj |    3 | 
+------+--------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from B;
+------+--------+------+
| pk   | value  | fk   |
+------+--------+------+
|    1 | katt   |    1 | 
|    2 | fjfjfj |    3 | 
+------+--------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from C;
+------+-------+
| pk   | value |
+------+-------+
|    1 | hei   | 
|    2 | nei   | 
|    3 | jeg   | 
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```